# Sentry Root Transaction name and operation name getting mixed up

Tags: sentry

I am using sentry for the monitoring of my golang gin project  , and i have defined my transcation for 3 APIs as follows

```
    span := sentry.StartSpan(c.Request.Context(), "C", sentry.TransactionName("C"))
    defer span.Finish()

    span := sentry.StartSpan(c.Request.Context(), "B", sentry.TransactionName("B"))
    defer span.Finish()

    span := sentry.StartSpan(c.Request.Context(), "A", sentry.TransactionName("A"))
    defer span.Finish()
```

But in the sentry dashboard, I am getting mixed-up data, A and C are being shown in the same row, which should not be the case

can anyone please tell me why this is happening, and how can I avoid it.

[image: A and C are being shown in the same row, which should not be the case]